# Integer Knapsack and Independent Set (Graph Theory) Related?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, graph-algorithm

In Algorithms-II course by Tim RoughGarden on Coursera while explaining the 0-1 knapsack problem , he mentions the following and I quote

" By taking away the Wn from the knapsack capacity, before we look at the residual    subproblem, we're in effect reserving a buffer for item N if we ever need it, and that's how we know we're feasible when we stick N back into this solution S*. This is analogous to deleting the penultimate vertex of the path, again as a buffer to ensure feasibility when we include the Nth vertex back into the Independent set problem."

Please explain this comparison between Knapsack Problem and Maximum Independent Set problem. How are they interrelated. Even though I searched

> [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_%28graph_theory%29)

but couldn't find any relation between the two.

Answer (score 2):

The way I understand this snippet, the author tries to explain how to obtain a smaller subproblem from the current problem.

In the case of the knapsack, he means that, given for instance weights `{5, 3, 7, 1, 4}` and a knapsack of size `15`, you can create a subproblem by selecting the first item and looking at the remaining space. That is, the remaining problem is to solve the knapsack problem for `{3, 7, 1, 4}` and knapsack size `10` (note that this is only part of the solution).

In the independent set you have something similar. Given the vertices `{A, B, C, D, E}` and edges `{(A, B), (A, D), (B, C), (C, D), (C, E), (D, E)}`, you can create a subproblem by selecting the first vertex (`A`) and looking at the remaining graph. All neighbors of `A` need to be removed, so the remaining problem is to find an independent set of the vertices `{C, E}` and edges `{(C, E)}`.

I must say that this similarity is quite a stretch, though.

Comment: Yes, the similarity is quite intriguing at first sight! But both have a notion of residual space / optimal residual sub problem which he has compared